# leaflet js determine which polygons are under polygon drawn by user

Tags: maps, leaflet

I am using leaflet js for drawing polygon on map and map already have drawn polygons but i am facing problem how to determine which polygons are under polygon which  is drawn by  user as follows in image[image: map with polygons]

Comment: green polygon is drawn by user

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [TurfJS's `intersect()` functionality](http://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect) to perform the geometry transformation/relation. Other libraries and utilities exist (e.g. the PostGIS spatial functions for geometries in databases), but Turf is my tool of choice for client-side javascript geospatial analysis.

Please be aware that there is no such thing as "polygon being under other polygon". I suggest you read about [spatial predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM#Spatial_predicates), and the difference between "overlap", "cover" and "intersect".

Comment: Hi, is there any working example to find/list the intersecting polygons with the drawn Polygon from a geojson file (containing a couple of dozens polygons)?